# using python psycopg2: multiple cursors (1 per thread) on same connection

Tags: multithreading, psycopg2, python-3.6

I have different threads running which all write to the same database (though not the same table).

Currently I have it setup that I create a connection, and pass that to each thread, which then creates it own cursor for writing.

I haven't implementing the writing to db part yet, but am wondering if not every thread needs it's own connection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Each thread should use a distinct connection to avoid problems with inconsistent states and to make debugging easier. On web servers, this is typically achieved by using a pooled connection. Each thread (http request processor) picks up a connection from the pool when it needs it and then returns it back to the pool when done. In your case, you can just create a new connection for each thread and pass it to the thread which can close it when done.